# JPA - Eclipselink - InheritanceType.JOINED not doing the correct JOIN

Tags: jpa, inheritance, eclipselink

I dont know if this is a bug or there is something I am missing, but there is a problem when you try to use Inheritance.JOINED when the superclass has a composite primary key.

I have the following classes:
(Superclass)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tipos_opciones_misiones")
@IdClass(TipoOpcionMisionId.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "clase", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@ReadOnly
public abstract class TipoOpcionMision{
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="tipo_mision")
    private TipoMision tipoMision;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "numero")
    private int numero;
}
```

And a child class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tipos_misiones_opciones_comercio_compra")
@DiscriminatorValue("COMERCIO_COMPRA")
public class TipoOpcionMisionComercioCompra extends TipoOpcionMision{

    @Column(name="valor")
    double valor;
}
```

When I try to get a list on objects "TipoOpcionMision" the generated SQL ignores that there is a composite key [tipo_mision, numero] and it just uses "t1.numero = t0.numero". There should also be a "t1.tipo_mision= t0.tipo_mision".

```
SELECT **list of fields***,  FROM tipos_misiones_opciones t0, tipos_misiones_opciones_comercio_compra t1 WHERE ((t0.tipo_mision = 'MISION_1') AND ((t1.numero = t0.numero) AND (t0.clase = 'COMERCIO_COMPRA')))
```

There is no errors, but I get false results because I am getting the values of the first row in the cartesian product.

I have tried to add:

```
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "tipo_mision", referencedColumnName = "tipo_mision"),
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "numero", referencedColumnName = "numero")
})
```

But program fails when starting with the following error:

```
Exception Description: A @PrimaryKeyJoinColumns was found on the annotated element [class TipoOpcionMisionComercioCompra]. When the entity uses a single primary key, only a single (or zero) @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn should be specified.
```

It seems that for some reason Eclipselink is ignoring tthat the superclass has a composite primary key.

Comment: Just noticed you have the ID being a foriegn key to itself. This design will not work; you are stuck in a circular relationship. JPA requires a foreign key/joincolumn definition for all components of a composite PK, and you are defining this entities identity to depend on its parent, which depends on its parent - endlessly. The mapping is wrong, and the PK class def wouldn't be able to handle it, so chances are good what you've got isn't loading this entity in your persistence unit. Use either a single/simple ID field and make FK references easier to manage, or setup some parent/child classes

Comment: Sorry Chris. Parent class is type TipoOpcionMision, not TipoMision. I made a mistake when writing this post trying to simplify my classes. There is no circular relationship.

Comment: @Chris What really intrigues me is the fact that PrimaryKeyJoinColumns fails because Eclipselink thinks that the Entity "uses a single primary key", which is false, a composite key is defined. Could it be a bug?

Comment: Maybe. If you turn on DDL generation and make the TipoOpcionMision a class instead of abstract, what does EclipseLink generate for that tipos_opciones_misiones table? What is in your TipoOpcionMisionId.class, and are you seeing any warnings or messages when this is deployed and EclipseLink is processing the TipoOpcionMision class? My guess is that it has a version of the class/persistence unit with only numero mapped as the ID, an early test perhaps that is still in your jar somehow, but I can't say yet what's going wrong.

Comment: Hi @Chris, thanks again. I have already tried to remove the "abstract" keyword but there were no changes.  You are right, Eclipselink thinks that only "numero" is the primary key, it is the field it uses in the join condition, ignoring "tipo_mision".

I have tried to use  PrimaryKeyJoinColumn (with tipo_mision) instead of PrimaryKeyJoinColumns (numero, tipo_mision). As expected, in that case it uses "tipo_mision" in the join condition ignoring that "numero" exists.
I've been diving in the JPA documentation but I cannt find what could be wrong. I am pretty covinced that it has ti be a bug.

Comment: Try mapping "tipo_mision" as a basic mapping instead, and enable eclipseLink logging ( https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging ) on finest to see what it shows during deployment when processing your class - it should state every mapping as it encounters it. Otherwise, create a small test case reproducing the issue and file a bug ( https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink/issues )